# Spark: creating new columns that contain "true" count and "false" count

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark to run some analysis on huge dataset. the problem is that I want to get the count of ture and false in a column. For example, if I run the code:

```
val areestTrue = df.groupBy("Year", "Arrest").count().sort(col("Year").desc)
areestTrue.show(50)
```

I get something like:

```
\+----+------+------+\
|Year|Arrest| count|\
\+----+------+------+\
|2023| false| 55039|\
|2023|  true|  7555|\
|2022| false|210722|\
|2022|  true| 27234|\
\+----+------+------+

areestTrue: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [Year: int, Arrest: boolean ... 1 more field]
```

However, I want this table to be like (year, count of true arrest, count of false arrest):

```
\+----+-----------+-----------+\
|Year|falseArrest| trueArrest|\
\+----+-----------+-----------+\
|2023|      55039|       7555|\
|2022|     210722|      27234|\
\+----+-----------+-----------+\
```

I tried to count only true values but it did not seems to be working:

```
val areestTrue = df.groupBy("Year", "Arrest").count("true").sort(col("Year").desc)
```

Do you guys have an idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot, this would work:

```
df\
.groupBy("Year")\
.pivot('Arrest')\
.agg(F.count("Arrest"))\
.show()
```

Input:

```
+----+------+
|Year|Arrest|
+----+------+
|2023|  True|
|2022|  True|
|2022|  True|
|2023| False|
|2022| False|
|2023|  True|
|2023| False|
|2023|  True|
|2023| False|
+----+------+
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+----+
|Year|False|True|
+----+-----+----+
|2022|    1|   2|
|2023|    3|   3|
+----+-----+----+
```